# Delete from hash table if match occurs while going thru a giant text of data

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have PowerShell script. This scripts reads line by line out of 300MB text of data. Then adds to hash table with following fields. So far I know how to add to a hash table. But now I want a condition where server matches a certain criteria , I want to delete entire row of data from hash table. Any help would be appreciated ? Original PowerShell script is huge, if you want I can put that here.

```
===ServerName==============OverAllsize======DB2size===========RMANsize========FileSize========Groups=============================================BackupType==========
=====================================================================================================================================================================
rsdbpc03.corpads.local        954.52          0.88            0.00            953.64          Clone_DR,MN_DB,MN_DB_DB2,MN_FS,MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days,UNIX_NP_FS01_7_Days   DB2full,Filefull,Fileincr
bpippa300p.corpads.local      0.01          0.00            0.00            0.01          JC_FS,JC_UNIX_FS01_INCR,UNIX_FS01_INCR   Fileincr       
hpp11002.corpads.local        0.09          0.00            0.00            0.09          LINUX_FS01_INCR,MN_FS,MN_LINUX_FS01_30days   Fileincr       
eddmna200u.corpads.local      0.01          0.00            0.00            0.01          MN_FS,MN_UNIX_NP_7_Days,UNIX_NP_FS01_7_Days   Filefull,Fileincr
HUD11003.corpads.local        88.80          80.03            0.00            8.77          JC_FS,JC_UNIX_NP_7_Days,UNIX_NP_FS01_7_Days   Filefull,Fileincr
nwcppl300p.corpads.local      945.52          0.00            0.00            945.52          backup,filesystem,Networker,NMC,Protection,server,servers   Filefull,Fileincr
```

I am trying below peice of code , will these work ?

```
$ht = @{}
$arr = @()
#more computation here
#now $arr has list of servers and $ht has all value
foreach ($server in $arr){
    $ht.GetEnumerator()| ForEach-Object  {
        if ($_.name -eq $server){
            $ht.Remove('$_.name') # this should remove entire row including all fields
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to show *some* code, but maybe not your entire script. Can you extract a dozen or so lines to demonstrate the specific issue you're having? Or write a representative sample from scratch? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for more pointers...

Comment: updated my thinking of code which should work . any idea ? i can't test since original code takes hours to go thru entire contents. Once you testify my thinking is correct , then i will test it out.

Comment: You can just do ```foreach ($server in $arr) { $ht.Remove($server) }```. If the key doesn't exist it will silently do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You won`t be able to Remove key/value pairs from the $ht hash while enumerating it. You first need to create a copy of the $ht hash using Clone().

```
$tHASH = $ht.Clone()

foreach ($server in $arr){
    $tHASH.GetEnumerator()| ForEach-Object  {
        if ($_.name -eq $server){
            $ht.Remove('$_.name') # this should remove entire row including all fields
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason they’re enumerating the keys in the first place is to do an equivalent of ```ContainsKey```. The entire code sample they provided can be reduced to ```foreach ($server in $arr) { $ht.Remove($server) }```…